# Text file not being found using relative path

Tags: c#

I created a text file in my working folder
it's not being picked up in the code
it's only picking up when I use an absolute path

```
string fileName = "Info.txt";            

if (File.Exists(fileName ))
{
    Console.WriteLine("File Exists");
    Console.WriteLine("File was created " + File.GetCreationTime(fileName));
    Console.WriteLine("File was last written to " + File.GetLastWriteTime(fileName));
}

else
{
    Console.WriteLine("File does not exist.");
}
```

Comment: Is the file `Info.txt` placed into the `bin` directory of your application?
Or please explain what you consider the `working folder`.

Comment: Its not in the bin directory

Comment: `File.Exists` will look in the `bin` directory. If you put it in there it will work.

Comment: @MuzzammilMahomed well, theres your problem.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("The current directory is {0}", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());`

Will print your current working directory if you want to know the exact path.

Comment: @L01NL Still not working

Comment: @MuzzammilMahomed
If you are using visual studio:
Find file in solution explorer -> Right click -> Properties -> Copy to output directory - Set to "Copy always". Then you have to build your solution CTRL + SHIFT + B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`File.Exists` is looking in the same directory as `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` unless you specify a different path.

> The path parameter is permitted to specify relative or absolute path information. Relative path information is interpreted as relative to the current working directory. To obtain the current working directory, see GetCurrentDirectory.

One reason `File.Exists` might still return false is if the application lacks access rights to the file

> If the caller does not have sufficient permissions to read the specified file, no exception is thrown and the method returns false regardless of the existence of path.